# write key and value from dictionary to csv with python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 2 keys are "text1" and "text2", the characteristic is key "text1" has a repeated character "A" but the number of element between 2 occurrence of "A" can be changed when I update dictionary "data" sometimes. I want to writer a header row in csv with all values from "A" to value before next "A", and the value from "text2" will be matched with column from header as below expected result in csv:

[image]

```py
import csv
data={
    "text1":("A","mouse","cat","A","mouse","cat","A","mouse","cat"),
    "text2":(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
}


with open("result.csv","w") as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
    writer_inline=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',',lineterminator=',')
    for i in range(0,len(data["text1"])):
        writer_inline.writerow([data["text1"][i]])
        if data["text1"][i]=="A" and i>1:
            continue

with open("result.csv","r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: what is your question? is your code not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to csv file from your `data` dictionary, you can use this example:

```py
import csv

data = {
    "text1": ("A", "mouse", "cat", "A", "mouse", "cat", "A", "mouse", "cat"),
    "text2": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
}

tmp = {}
for k, v in zip(data["text1"], data["text2"]):
    tmp.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

with open("result.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerow(tmp.keys())
    writer.writerows(zip(*tmp.values()))
```

Creates `result.csv`:

```
A,mouse,cat
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works ! let me research more on 'zip', it is the 1st time i face

Comment: Hi Andrej, btw, can you share how you handle if you have multi 'v' like  :                               for k, v1,v2,v3,v4 in zip(data["text1"], data["text2"]):
    tmp.setdefault(k, []).append([v1,v2,v3,v4])